# Handling socket process in a class in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6 and new to sockets and threads.

I need to write a socket code for listinging certain ports. Following is my related socket class:

```
class SocketServer(object):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, host, sock_port, buffsize=1024):
        self.hostname = host
        self.sock_port = sock_port
        self.buffsize = buffsize
        self.socket = None

    def start(self):
        print "Listening: "
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind((self.hostname, self.sock_port))
        self.socket.listen(10)

        while True:
            conn, address = self.socket.accept()
            thread.start_new_thread(handle_data, (conn, self.buffsize))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = socketServer(ip, port)
    try:
        server.start()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

`handle_data` is the function that listens to relatted certain port:

```
def handle_data(conn, buffsize):
    while True:
        try:
            _veri = conn.recv(buffsize)
            if not _veri:
                break
        except Exception as e:
            break
        # Do something else
    conn.close()
```

It all works fine, but `handle_data` have some long code so I want to write it as a class.

First question is, whow can I write it as a class? Second, threading a class in socket listening have any disadventages (considerable memory usage difference etc.) ove threading a function?

Comment: Not clearly a solution, but a look at the [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/socketserver.html) module may be useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between threading a class and threading a function.

Basically, every thread that you'll start will run a function.

Then, threading a class implies to write a class with a *entry point* function, which will manage your instance. All you will have to write is:

```
thread.start_new_thread(myClassInstance.handle_data, (conn, self.buffsize))
```

The only *difference* is that using a class, you'll have a very very low overhead due to the `self` argument passed to every method call you do.
I think that at this point, you can neglect it.

Comment: Will `myClassInstance` be derived from  `threading.Thread`? Sorry for such questions but I am quite noice in that subject.

Comment: @FallenAngel No, you don't need. In Python, functions are first class citizens. The consequence is that `instance.function` is a bound method which can be called without the `self` argument. To illustrate what I am saying, let's say you have a class with a method `dance(self, time)`, in order to call it, you need a `self `and a `time` parameter. The `self` is the instance class. In Python, the `self` parameter is automatically bound using an instance. Thus, you only have to give the `time` parameter. Here, it's the same. Your handle_data `self` parameter is bound to `myClassInstance`.